# How do you fix the "could not be opened. Please check the logs" error in Unity?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I just downloaded Unity on my PC, but whenever I try making a new project, I keep getting the same error. I've reinstalled unity hub and the editor 3 times already. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Picture of the Error]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error tells you? Check the logs!